# Pip for Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

How do I install Pip for Python 3.8 ? I made 3.8 my default Python version.

```
sudo apt install python3.8-pip
```

gives

> unable to locate package python3.8-pip

and running

```
python3.8 -m pip install [package]
```

gives

> no module named pip

I can't run `sudo apt install python3-pip` because it installs pip for Python 3.6

Comment: if you installed any standard python distribution then PIP already comes with Python and there is no need to install it.

Comment: The thing is current pip is using 3.6 which I don't want to use since I'm working with Python 3.8

Comment: Then you need to use the PIP from Python 3.8. use `python -m pip` where `python` is whatever python 3.8 binary

Comment: @juanpa Based on `apt`, OP's probably using Debian/Ubuntu. Their Python distros don't include pip by default.

Comment: @wjandrea then they *definitely shouldn't be using their system python for anything*

Comment: @juanpa Agreed. Personally I would install Python 3.8 system-wide (and not make it default), then make a virtualenv to install pip, but there are other good ways.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Install pip [the official way](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
```

> made 3.8 my default Python version

It depends on how you did that, but it might break something in your OS.  For example some packages on Ubuntu 18.04 might depend on `python` being `python2.7` or `python3` being `python3.6` with some pip packages preinstalled.

Comment: **You don't need to install PIP for Python 3.8**: "pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4"

Comment: ..."[if] downloaded from python.org or if you are working in a Virtual Environment created by virtualenv or pyvenv."

Comment: Got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'`

Comment: @West that's a problem of python installation, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239829/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils-util

Comment: @Ryabchenko's answer solves the distutils error and should be the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63281773/3996580

Answer (score 47):

```
sudo apt install python3.8
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.8 get-pip.py
```

Comment: If I've already got IPython installed via pip3, is manually installing Python 3.8 going to break anything?

Comment: Thanks that python3.8-distutils saved my time

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 26):

If you installed Python3.8 using `apt`, the pip documentation [advises *against*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) using the `get-pip.py` script:

> Be cautious if you are using a Python install that is managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.

The [same page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) suggests running:

```
python3.8 -m pip --version
```

to determine if pip is already installed.  I installed Python 3.8 on an Ubuntu18 machine using `apt install python3.8`, and I verified with the command above that it includes pip.  It appears that Ubuntu package doesn't install a `pip` command that you can run directly.  But you can run it using the python3.8 binary directly instead, anywhere you would have used `pip`:

```
python3.8 -m pip install [package]
```

Comment: Your command gives me `/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip`.

Comment: Thanks for the more specified pip call

Answer (score 1):

you can try updating line #1 from /usr/bin/pip3 to #!/usr/bin/python3.8 as below

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
# GENERATED BY DEBIAN

import sys

# Run the main entry point, similarly to how setuptools does it, but because
# we didn't install the actual entry point from setup.py, don't use the
# pkg_resources API.
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

What I used to install pip according to the current version of default python is:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ensurepip` module:

```
python3.8 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```